# I forgot to enter a payment ID

Tags: payment-id

I just entered the wallet ID but not entered a payment ID. How can I recover my payment ? Please help me.

Comment: Did you send to yourself or to exchange?

Answer (score 1):

If you omit a payment id, the monero still reaches the destination wallet owner, but that wallet owner does not have the information needed to know what the incoming monero is intended for (ie, for which of my clients is it). You then have to ask the recipient to do the manual work of checking they received the monero, and credit them to your account specifically. For this, you will need at least the transaction id, but more info (such as amount) is better, as anyone else could otherwise claim this txid and "brute force" the recipient.
The recipient could also ask you to prove your transaction. This is done using the `get_tx_key` command in monero-wallet-cli. This prevents any spoofing. In any case, this is manual work for the recipient, so please try to remember to include any payment id that's requested next time.